# Best way to structure controllers, services code on AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I'm starting with AngularJS and I have some problems because I found on the internet a lot of examples about how declare the code, but generally the code is different.

For example on the controller:

```
(function(){
  angular.module('myApp')
    .controller('myCtrl', myCtrl);

  function myCtrl($scope, Restangular, myFactory) {
     /* Code here */
  }
)();
```

In other pages I found this way:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp');
myApp.controller('myCtrl', myCtrl);
myCtrl.$inject = [$scope,Restangular, myFactory];
function myCtrl($scope, Restangular, myFactory) {
  /* Code here */
}
```

And, not being enough .. I found this other way:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp');
myApp.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, Restangular, myFactory) {
  /*Code here*/
});
```

I'm a little confusing and I don't know what is the best way to declare my components (controllers, factory, constants etc...)

Thanks for advance.

Comment: Your second way should be `myCtrl.$inject = ['$scope','Restangular', 'myFactory'];`

Comment: I generally prefer to use second (corrected_^^_) way

Comment: runTarm u alright, I typed wrong. PSL, why I should use myCtrl.$inject...? Is not enough with put that on:  function myCtrl($scope, Restangular ....) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What matters is to understand the similarities and differences between all these ways of doing. Then you'll use the technique that you prefer.

Let's examine the first one:

```
(function(){
  angular.module('myApp')
    .controller('myCtrl', myCtrl);

  function myCtrl($scope, Restangular, myFactory) {
     /* Code here */
  }
)();
```

First of all, it does everything inside a self-called anonymous function. The reason for using this JavaScript trick is to be able to declare functions without polluting the global namespace, and thus having myCtrl being a global function accessible from everywhere, and potentially conflicting with another global function.

Inside the anonymous function, a function named `myCtrl` is defined. `angular.module('myApp')` asks angular to return a reference to a previously defined module, and the controller function is added as a controller to the returned module. It's equivalent to

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp');
myApp.controller('myCtrl', myCtrl);
```

except it doesn't need a variable.

This technique has a drawback: it won't support minification, for the reason described in the section "A Note on minification" of https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_05, unless a preprocessing tool like ngAnnotate is used to transform this code to minifiable code.

Let's now look at the second one:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp');
myApp.controller('myCtrl', myCtrl);
myCtrl.$inject = ['$scope','Restangular', 'myFactory'];
function myCtrl($scope, Restangular, myFactory) {
  /* Code here */
}
```

Here, a global variable `myApp` is defined. That's bad. A global function `myCtrl` is also defined. Thanks to the use of $inject, this code will support minification, though.

Let's look at the last one:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp');
myApp.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, Restangular, myFactory) {
  /*Code here*/
});
```

Here again, a global variable `myApp` is defined. The controller function is now defined as an anonymous inline function. This avoids defining a global function. This code, once again, is not minifiable.

My advice: if you don't use ngAnnotate, use the following:

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', 'Restangular', 'myFactory', function($scope, Restangular, myFactory) {
   ...
}]);
```

It doesn't need a self-calling anonymous function, supports minification, and doesn't define any global variable or function.

If you use ngAnnotate, the above code can be simplified to

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, Restangular, myFactory) {
   ...
});
```

And finally, if you really want your controller function to have a name (for debugging purposes, for example, although I've never needed it):

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', 'Restangular', 'myFactory', function MyCtrl($scope, Restangular, myFactory) {
   ...
}]);
```

or, with ngAnnotate:

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('MyCtrl', function MyCtrl($scope, Restangular, myFactory) {
   ...
});
```

Comment: Great explanation! I also encourage the use of [ng-annotate](https://github.com/olov/ng-annotate) as it will prevent a silly dependencies/parameters mismatch.

Comment: Great explanation JB Nizet. You really has helped me a lot with this. I have on small doubt, is necessary use 'use strict' on my code? I really don't understand how that's works and when I need to use that. Thanks for advance again Nizet.

Comment: No, it's not necessary. To be frank, I'm not really sure how it works, especially if strict and non-strict scripts end up being concatenated in the same JS file.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to declare your dependancies twice, if you use a minifier. In most cases the third way will be fine.